# How do I include extensions in the tel: URI?

Tags: html, mobile, uri, phone-number, tel

I currently have a webpage serving up phone numbers, some of these phone numbers have extensions so I have written the HTML like this:

```
<a href="tel:+44-1234-567;ext=88">+44-1234-56788</a> / <a href="tel:+44-1234-567;ext=99">+44-1234-56799</a
```

When I hit this page in my Android browser and tap one of the phone numbers, it loads up in my phone dialer (UK Samsung Galaxy s2 stock) as:

```
+44-1234-567;ext=88
```

which I don't think is correct. Surely it should omit the `;ext=` word.

Have I misread the RFC for implementing `tel`?

Comment: Just because you’ve read the spec correctly doesn’t mean the phone dialer has implemented it correctly. ☹

Comment: Has anyone tested all of these answers on iPhone and Android? I would guess 90%+ click to call calls would come from fairly recent iOS and Android devices. Sure you might have 50%+ desktop visitors on your site, but those people are probably dialing by hand.

Answer (score 44):

Seems the proper way to do it is use a comma:

`<a href="tel:441234567,88">+44-1234-567 ext.88</a>`

Just tested with iPhone and Android OS 2.1. Using `;ext=88` converts the *ext* bit into a number that is dialed with the extension (so it dials something like 35888 instead of 88).

Comment: This answer is definitely wrong as you removed the "+" completely. I don't understand why so many users upvoted this, see my answer below for the correct version.

Answer (score 22):

Comment for [How do I include extensions in the tel: URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482633/how-do-i-include-extensions-in-the-tel-uri)

**As of June 2021** the RFC3966 `;ext=` syntax still isn't implemented by Android, and it's inelegantly implemented by iOS.

Using `;ext=123` as an example:

- Android: after the call connects a modal window appears asking `Send the following tones? 396123` with `No` and `Yes` buttons. "Send the following tones?" is a precise technical description of what will happen if the user taps `Yes`, but it is probably not the best wording for the average user.
- Android converts `;ext=123` into `396123` because it treats the letters the same way as if you were dialing something like `1-800-FLOWERS`, and this is a broken implementation of the syntax.
- iOS provides an option to the left of the Disconnect button that says `Dial “ext=…”`. When you tap on this "button" it will dial the extension number. This is inelegant and has bad usability because the "button" doesn't look like a button — it's just plain text — and because you can't see the extension number.
- In addition, when you first tap on a phone link in iOS it presents a button at the bottom of the screen which partially rewrites the phone number into a local format, but which also preserves most of the `;ext=` syntax, e.g. `Call +1 (555) 555-5555;ext123`. This is also inelegant, and it's ugly besides.

If you instead use just a `;` which is supposed to mean "wait," as in "wait until the auto attendant message ends and then automatically dial the extension":

- iOS: tapping the link displays a button stating `Call +1 (555) 555-5555;123` which is slightly less ugly than the button described above.
- iOs provides the same extension-dialing "button" described above except the extension number is visible, e.g. `Dial “123”`. It still has the other usability problems.
- iOS does not automatically dial the extension after the message ends.
- Android: after the call connects a modal window appears asking `Send the following tones? 123` with `No` and `Yes` buttons.
- Android does not automatically dial the extension after the message ends.

So for now, **as of June 2021** it seems that **the only way to include extensions in `tel:` links that will actually work is to use either `;` for "wait" or `,` for "pause"**:

- `<a href="tel:+1-555-555-5555;123">555-555-5555 ext. 123</a>` — this will provide a UI component which the user can invoke to dial the extension. The usability of the UI component depends on the OS; neither are great, but Android's is arguably better.
- `<a href="tel:+1-555-555-5555,123">555-555-5555 ext. 123</a>` — this will automatically dial the extension a couple seconds after the call connects. **Note:** This mechanism will not work with voicemail systems that don't accept user input until the auto attendant message ends.

Answer (score 12):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html), you can add what you want like so 12345678;ext=123

See [RFC 3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's from 2012 but is a valid source.

Comment: [W3.Org](http://www.w3.org) relates above mentioned RFC 3966 as the most broadly supported scheme https://www.w3.org/TR/mwabp/#bp-interaction-uri-schemes

Answer (score 5):

In all the examples I saw, the value of `ext` is contained in the full number. So try including 88 in the `href` value:

```
<a href="tel:+44-1234-56788;ext=88">+44-1234-56788</a>
```

Comment: It still tells you which part of the whole number corresponds to the extension. Don't know how would browsers handle that, though. I'd have to check the RFC.

Answer (score 5):

For those still wondering about this problem: I've found it best to use this format:

```
<a href="tel:+13235798328;22">
```

Comment: I love how every answer to this question is completely different lol

Answer (score 4):

[Standards at thenewcode](http://thenewcode.com/536/Adding-Phone-Numbers-To-Web-Pages-With-HTML5-and-Microdata) from 3 months ago suggest using a microdata pause.

**`<a href="tel:+13235798328p22">`**

**Related**: 
Different standards persist across different external platforms and may change the processing of URIs. [Click to call](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/click-to-call/)
 features on Google Developers docs do not specify

*Example:* 
Office's Skype [uses x to represent extension within skype](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Edit-phone-number-f9cc6786-344f-4ad3-bab0-6d58ce5e8bf7).

Comment: [apple dev](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) also does not appear to have a standard for URI extension

Comment: Nice addition @systemaddict. Unfortunately, 'p' auto-converted to a number on Android v7 on my Samsung in US.

Answer (score 3):

I don't get the answers to this question - I think the're wrong. The correct link would look like this:

```
<a href="tel:+441234567,88">+44-1234-567 ext. 88</a>
```

Comment: it is the only format that works on both Android and iOS

Answer (score 3):

I feel like this is kind of a cop-out answer, but if this is not implemented consistently across devices yet, probably best to just not include the extension and let people dial it by hand:

`<a href="tel:+441234567">+44-1234-567 ext. 88</a>`

or

`<a href="tel:+441234567">+44-1234-567</a> ext. 88`

Better to make the user do more work than to send 1/2 your users to the wrong extension.