# HTML Click to call phone numbers with extension that work with both iPhone and Android <a href=tel:

Tags: href, twilio-click-to-call, tel

I've tried the following ways to use the 123-456-7890 for making click to call links including extension numbers that work on iPhones and Androids.  Almost all of these ways work with Android and I haven't found one that works with iPhones.  I'm adding this code into gmail email signatures to test.

```
 1. <a href="tel:123-456-7890p123">123-456-7890</a>
 2. <a href="tel:123-456-7890w123">123-456-7890</a>
 3. <a href="tel:123-456-7890,123">123-456-7890</a>
 4. <a href="tel:123-456-7890,,123">123-456-7890</a>
 5. <a href="tel:123-456-7890;123">123-456-7890</a>
 6. <a href="tel:123-456-7890;ext=123">123-456-7890</a>
```

[image: See attached screenshot].

Comment: On https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482633/how-do-i-include-extensions-in-the-tel-uri it's said that most of these (used to) work...

Comment: Have you read the docs and tried the techniques in there? 
 https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html

Comment: B. Go - Yes, I've tried all of those methods in gmail signatures and all of them get the "call cannot be completed" message, or something similar, for iPhones.

Comment: Wyck - I don't see any information about methods for phone numbers with extension numbers.  If you have a link to info about that, please share.

Comment: <a href="tel:123-456-7890,,123#">123-456-7890</a>This method works with iPhones and Androids.  I was originally putting the 3 digit area code in parenthesis like this - "tel:(123) 456-7890 - and iPhones do not like this for some reason.  If you use hyphens like this - "tel:123-456-7890" it works just fine with iPhones.  I would imagine that one or more of the methods I originally posted will work with both iPhone and Android too if you don't place the area code within parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

123-456-7890This method works with iPhones and Androids. I was originally putting the 3 digit area code in parenthesis like this - "tel:(123) 456-7890 - and iPhones do not like this for some reason. If you use hyphens like this - "tel:123-456-7890" it works just fine with iPhones. I would imagine that one or more of the methods I originally posted will work with both iPhone and Android too if you don't place the area code within parenthesis