# "tel:" on website is loosing the extension which are passed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

On our website we are using extension with phone number to dial. 
Try 1 : `<a href="tel:12345678,123">` 
Try 2 : `<a href="tel:12345678,,123">` 
Try 3 : `<a href="tel:12345678p123">`

In Try 1 and 2 we are losing 123 in lot of calls. Try 3 isnt working.

Can anyone suggest whats the right way to do it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I include extensions in the tel: URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482633/how-do-i-include-extensions-in-the-tel-uri)

Comment: as I have said , is still losing the extension

Comment: Oh that's just a auto comment when a question is marked as a dupe. Read the other question because it is exactly what you need. Also, as the comment on the other question mentions, you can implement it correctly but the phone might not of implemented it according to the code. read thru the different answers

Comment: I believe 1 is correct, but are you suggesting that some clicks to the same number do not work - OR - that some systems you call to not understand the extension?

Comment: @Huangism understood it was dupe. Yes it says the same thing but the solution there also isnt working

Comment: @scunliffe I believe that on few mobile devices when click of call button are not taking the extension to the dial pad

Comment: @Arjit the solution there are how it is supposed to be implemented, if the phone company don't make their software to use this, there is nothing we can do. Not everything has an ideal solution

Comment: @Huangism Thanks a lot for this pointer.  I just wanted to know if phone company doesnt allow. 

Any documentation that I can find ?

Comment: @Arjit not necessarily the phone companies, could be whoever makes the software and any documentation would be hard to track, as developers we can only implement things the right way and hope for the best

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the tag in the correct way, try this:

```html
<a href="tel:12345678,123">12345678 ext.123</a>
```

Comment: I have added the anchor tag which I had missed in the question